# Creating Address Labels in ASP.NET App

Tags: .net, asp.net, ms-word, repeater, label

i have a Simple app for inserting my clients details into the Database.
The Fields are 
1) ClientID
2) frstnm
3) midnm
4) lastnm
5) Add1
6) Add2
7) City
8) State
........

Now what i want is the generation of address Labels for my company to send them physical letters to remind them about payments,pending bills etc.

I just want them to alligned Like this

> **Adam John Clarke**
>   XYZ Street ABC Road ( This is Add1)
>   infront of ABC Cafe ( Example Add2)
>   **City Name**
>   **State Name**
>   Mobile Number

The Point here is that I want them **Exported to MS-Word** to be printed in Columns i.e. Two Columns of each page in MS-WORD and in One column 5 names and other 5 names ( For Example)

The Problem is that when i use repeater the Text is not formatted in Columns Style in MS-Word.

The Problem is Tear the individual Labels and Paste them on Physical Envelope so if i print only one side of the Word Document The Pages go Waste and i have loads of them to print.
So at the end of the day i have lost many papers..

Is there any solution for that..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

instead of spitting out HTML, why not spit out either [WordML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/odcXMLRef/html/odcXMLRefLegalNotice.asp?frame=true) (the native xml-like markup language used by MS Word) or [RTF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140277%28v=office.10%29.aspx) formatted documents?

Yes, it's a bit harder to do, but you'll get exactly what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial for RTF (http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/17964/0/page/2). The WordML will work pretty much the same, it's just the markup is different, and IMO, easier to grok

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for a solution to this you may find this recent CodeProject article of some help to you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/847159/Printing-Address-Labels-From-ASP-Net

Answer (score -1):

Turn the label pages upside down and feed them through the printer again.